# Why some CRS are deprecated in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3

I tried to specify the Pulkovo 1942 / Gauss-Kruger 13N ([EPSG:28473](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/28473/)) CRS for my QGIS project. But it is deprecated. I have never seen such issue before.

Why it is deprecated?

[image]

The QGIS version is 3.6.3

Comment: @Taras I'm glad to see here such a patriotic Ukrainian user as you

Comment: Thank you, for your outstanding and straightforward position !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

EPSG:28473 is deprecated in the EPSG database in 2002. The corresponding change request is https://epsg.org/closed-change-request/browse/id/2002.36 and the reason for the request was "Rationalise Gauss-Kruger zone names"

The new code to use is EPSG:2503
https://epsg.org/crs_2503/Pulkovo-1942-Gauss-Kruger-CM-75E.html

Answer (score 14):

In this case because of a

> Change of CRS name to indicate longitude of origin.

As stated in [the link](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/pulkovo-1942-gauss-kruger-13n/) you provided, this is a **registry decision** (see [@user30184's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/400987/93656)) rather than a software internal state or issue. QGIS only reads out properties from the [*proj*](https://proj.org/index.html) registry library; i.e. the *OGC WKT* representation of this CRS:

```
PROJCS["Pulkovo 1942 / Gauss-Kruger 13N (deprecated)",GEOGCS["Pulkovo 1942",DATUM["Pulkovo_1942",SPHEROID["Krassowsky 1940",6378245,298.3,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7024"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6284"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4284"]],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",75],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","28473"],AXIS["Y",EAST],AXIS["X",NORTH]]
```

Note that you are supposed to

> Use EPSG:2503 instead.

Comment: @Taras see my edit.

Answer (score 13):

### Update from January 2024

Spatialreference.org is now [maintained](https://github.com/OSGeo/spatialreference.org) and updated alongside PROJ development !

---

### Original/old answer

A caution to folks still using [spatialreference.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20231230084854/https://spatialreference.org/) :

| #### [image] It is not maintained, with the last update in 2013. |
| --- |

Use a modern source, including:

1. The official EPSG registry: https://epsg.org
2. A recent version of PROJ, e.g., see the output from `projinfo EPSG:28473`
3. Or a slightly less out-of-date third party resource http://epsg.io/28473 (see EPSG database version at the bottom of web page)

Comment: Wow ... thank you for a tip, I have never paid attention to *Last update: 2013*