# What is the correct coverage area of EPSG:2901: Australia or Montana, US?

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg

The two main websites I check CRS info disagree about what the CRS EPSG:2901 is intended for.

Curious whether anyone can shed some light on this conflict.

https://epsg.io/2901-area says Australia

https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2901/ says Montana in the United States

Comment: they don't disagree. See [here](https://epsg.io/2901). Note that this link is for the projection, while yours is for "area"

Comment: so the string "EPSG:2901" is ambiguous between an area and a projection? What exactly is an area?

Comment: I will leave that to EPSG database expert, I can only speculate the "area" is a predefined bounding box.  I don't see them being ambiguous though since they refer to different things, they just happen to share the same ID. The "area" is not a projection so it is not possible to use it as such

Comment: seems like it might be australia specific https://epsg.io/?q=Australia%20kind%3AAREA

Comment: no, there are [3500](https://epsg.io/?q=kind%3AAREA) of them, everywhere

Comment: Keep in mind that spatialreference.org is not maintained, the last update in 2013. more details in https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/400994/99589

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EPSG.io and spatialrefenece.com are third party web sites, for definitive information on EPSG codes you should probably use the official EPSG registry ~
[EPSG Geodetic Parameter Dataset](https://epsg.org/home.html)

Searching with 2901 on the EPSG registry shows us that the code is used for both a **CRS**

https://epsg.org/crs_2901/NAD83-HARN-Montana-ft.html?

and an **Extent**

https://epsg.org/extent_2901/Australia-138-E-to-144-E-8-S-to-12-S-SC54-onshore.html

In the EPSG registry, all geodetic parameters are codified, not just CRS, you can see from the search results parameters that have codes.

[image: List of EPSG parameters]

So if we look at the CRS NAD83-HARN-Montana-ft

[image: NAD83-HARN-Montana-ft]

We can see that the code for the **CRS** is 2901, that it is projected, that it acts on an **Extent** *USA - Montana* which has a code 1395

and if we explore further in the HTML page we can see that the coordinate system used is *Cartesian 2D CS. Axes: easting, northing (X,Y). Orientations: east, north. UoM: ft.* which has a code 4495.

It uses a BASE CRS *NAD83(HARN)* with code 4152

it uses the SPCS83 Montana zone (International feet) CONVERSION which has a code 15338

etc. etc.

The WKT2 gives us a summary of this too:

https://epsg.org/crs/wkt/id/2901

PROJCRS["NAD83(HARN) / Montana (ft)",BASEGEOGCRS["NAD83(HARN)",DATUM["NAD83 (High Accuracy Reference Network)",ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]],ID["EPSG",7019]],ID["EPSG",6152]],ID[**"EPSG",4152**]],CONVERSION["SPCS83 Montana zone (International feet)",METHOD["Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)",ID["EPSG",9802]],PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",44.25,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9102]]],PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",-109.5,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9102]]],PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",49,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9102]]],PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",45,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9102]]],PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",1968503.937,LENGTHUNIT["foot",0.3048,ID["EPSG",9002]]],PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0,LENGTHUNIT["foot",0.3048,ID["EPSG",9002]]],ID[**"EPSG",15338**]],CS[Cartesian,2,ID[**"EPSG",4495**]],AXIS["Easting (X)",east],AXIS["Northing (Y)",north],LENGTHUNIT["foot",0.3048,ID["EPSG",9002]],ID[**"EPSG",2901**]]